# Question on the calculation of the flux of a subtance at a point across any surface

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, vectors, transport-phenomena

How would one notate the operation leading to Eqn(1)?

The flux of a substance at a point $P$ is represented by the vector $f_i$, and its vector components ($\vec f_x,\vec f_y,\vec f_z$) are the fluxes along the coordinate axes *x, y*, and *z*, respectively. According to Carslaw and Jaeger (1959)*, the flux of this substance across any other surface through point $P$ with an outward-pointing normal having direction cosines ($\lambda, \mu, \nu$) relative to these axes would be equal to
$$\lambda \vec f_x +\mu \vec f_y +\nu \vec f_z  \tag{1}$$

Let's denote this new flux vector $g_i$. The outward-pointing normal vector to the surface can be a unit normal vector $u_i$:
$$\tag{2} u_i=(\vec u_x, \vec u_y, \vec u_z)=(\lambda \hat i, \mu \hat k, \nu \hat j)$$

I understand that if we took the scalar (dot) product of the flux vector and normal vector we obtain a scalar:
$$\tag{3} g=f_i u_i= (f_x\hat i+f_y \hat j+f_z 
\hat k)\cdot(\lambda \hat i+ \mu \hat k+ \nu \hat j)$$
$$=\lambda f_x +\mu f_y +\nu f_z$$

But it seems to obtain Eqn(1) one would need to perform a scalar-vector multiplication using the scalar result of Eqn(3) and the unit normal vector $u_i$. How would one notate this operation? I.e., how would one notate the operation leading to Eqn(1)?

My thoughts:
In tensor (indicial) notation:$$g_j=(f_i u_i)u_j \tag{4}$$
In matrix notation:$$\bf{g}=\bf{(f \cdot u) u} \tag{5}$$

*From Carslaw and Jaeger:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Eqn. 1 doesn't make sense to me.  Eqn. 3 gives the component of the flux in the direction normal to the prescribed surface.

Comment: @ChetMiller Eqn(3) gives the component (the scalar value) of the flux $\vec f$ in the direction $\vec u$. If we now want to know what the magnitude and direction of that component would we not just multiply it by the unit vector $\vec u$ ? I added the text from Carslaw & Jaeger, their derivation of my Eqn(1). Perhaps (likely) I am not understanding this.

Comment: @ChetMiller I think I found a wiki on this operation, the "[vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection)".